# How to do a keyboard mapping for CR and Shift-CR

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, keyboard-layout

To do a mapping for <kbd>return</kbd> I can do:

```
"When in normal mode, treat an enter like insert+enter
:nnoremap <CR> i<CR>
```

However, I would also like to map a shift-enter as:

```
:nnoremap <Shift-CF> O
```

What would be the proper way to enter this in?

I tried this but it doesn't do anything -- regardless of whether I hold shift or not, the mapping always does the first one:

```
"When in normal mode, treat an enter like insert+enter
:nnoremap <CR> i<CR>      <-- always doing this one (maybe overwriting the other?)
:nnoremap <s-CR> O
```

---

**Update**: it seems this is not possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter.

Comment: @filbranden what is 'deoplete' ?

Comment: it's a completion plug-in. That question is essentially about using Shift-Enter as well. I wanted to mark this one as a duplicate, but I don't know if that one is best... Perhaps if you'd want to self answer with your update (that should be an answer rather than an edit), that would be better actually.

Comment: This might be possible with xterms modifyOtherKeys.